# Is such a chart possible in Excel?

Tags: excel, charts

I wanted to know if creating such a chart was possible using the functions available in Excel (inc. VBA)?

[image]

In summary:

- The outer-bars update based on the extreme values of the data
- The inner blue shaded bar represents one standard deviation around the
  mean
- The current value is the latest recorded value
- The arrow represents the 3 month trend (either up or down)

I'd ideally want the above to be auto-refreshing with the source data coming in from an external feed.

Is the above possible using the charts + functions in excel? I'm not looking for a blow-by-blow description, just broadly the tools/methods you would use to achieve such a display of data.

Comment: There is no chart there, you have cropped it to death.

Comment: The image above is the method of displaying data I am asking about, there isn't anything else to show but i've included a link to the original source here: http://russellinvestments.com/helping-advisors/EconomyMarkets/EconomicIndicatorsDashboard/EconomicIndicatorsDashboard.aspx

Comment: I really wouldn't imagine Excel being the correct tool for you here, you would be able to recreate it in matplotlib, but it's definitely (extremely) non trivial to do so. You could always recreate it in html, as most of the work is done already, all you would have to do is link to your own data.  Charts are deceiving, they are simple t look at, but a lot of time there is an awful lot of care and attention needed to create them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To clarify, I am not entirely interested in the actual layout/design shown above, it was more the functionality/mechanics if excel could support such a chart

Comment: Creating the inner and outer bar is quite easy. Just use an ordinary bar chart and put them on top of each other (with primary and secondary axis). Done. Built into standard Excel and no problem. Yet, the orange box on top of the bars (with the arrow above) is not standard and would have to be added manually or using VBA.

Comment: If you don't want to recreate it outright, then I suppose you could have some variation of a bar plot, or even a candlestick chart if you can manage to rotate it. The annotations however are a different matter.

Comment: @ajsp Why rotate? What do you want to rotate? There are vertical bars (called columns) and horizontal bars (called bars). I am starting to wonder if you even have Excel installed and had a look at the available charts lately. Here is a very basic sample I just drafted: http://imgur.com/cPv265Q

Comment: @Ralph That is pretty much what I was after, if you plotted that in Excel using two bar plots? The only outstanding items would be a marker for current value.

Comment: @Ralph 11 I was thinking about using the wick of the candle for the max and min range, where the body of the candle would provide the typical range. OHLC, where O=Max Typical Range, C=Min Typical Range, H=Max Extreme Range, L=Min Extreme Range. But candlesticks are traditionally vertical, where the user wants a horizontal representation, hence my comment about rotation was purely visual.

Comment: Here is a link to the file with the above chart: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2365ihfkbr6o8nh/StackOverflow_Question_38280984_Slider-Bar-Chart.xlsm?dl=0 As mentioned in a comment before: you'll have to add the current value manually or using VBA as Excel can only overlay **two** charts on top of each other (here two bar charts) but not a third.